# why I am receiving the errors, when I want to launch my app?

Tags: flutter, adb

this is that error that I received.

**Error:-** ADB exited with exit code 1

Performing Streamed Install

**adb:-** failed to install F:\My Project\FirstApp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1367571730.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install adb manually on your windows.

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem is occurred because your devise storage is full first of all make free space in your device after that try again. it will work.